# Implementing Random Forest rolling window forecast in R

Tags: forecasting, random-forest, moving-window

I want to forecast a dependent variable and I have some independent variables. First I shifted the dependent variable up, such that I have a supervised problem. For instance in January 2000 the independent variables stay the same, but the response is the value of February 2000 in this case (forecast horizon h=1). I wanted to use a rolling window framework. For example observations in time t= 1,..,10 are used to fit a random forest, than the independent variables of observation t=11 are used to predict the value of response in t=12. After that the error is calculated by subtracting the prediciton from the actual value of the response. Than the window rolls to 2,...,11 and the procedure is repeated accordingly. Eventually the MSE can be calculated from all the errors. I coded this function myself (using ranger library) and I wanted to tune the mtry hyperparameter by looping over all possible mtry values (amount of independent variables), save the MSE and take the mtry with the lowest MSE as optimal mtry. However it is giving values as low as mtry=1. I wonder if my understanding of rolling window walk forward validation is correct?

Comment: Have you tried using tidymodels?  I think they have implemented this sort of validation scheme.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write your own code here.  `{tidymodels}` has a very good implementation of the validation scheme you're describing in the `rolling_origin` function.  See the docs [here](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/rolling_origin.html).